# Firebase Crashlytics configuration issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I followed instructions for setting up crashlytics from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

But when my app executes,

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

The app is crashing with message `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException', reason: '[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'`

From googling, I somebody saying we should add following code in `Info.plist` file.

```
<key>Fabric</key>
    <dict>
     <key>APIKey</key>
     <string>your_key</string>
     <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
         <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
         <dict/>
        <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Crashlytics</string>
        </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

But, where I can find APIKey if I am following https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

Comment: This may help:https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/settings/api-keys.html

Answer (score 5):

If you're installing Crashlytics to be used via Fabric, you should follow the installation instructions on https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install

Crashlytics via Firebase doesn't require Fabric API keys and doesn't use the `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])` call to initialize.

Comment: Note: Crashlytics with Fabric is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I added `FirebaseApp.configure()` before Fabric line and it works for me